# Sorting columns of a Matrix based on values in a different Matrix

Tags: java, sorting, matrix, pca

I am writing java code to implement [Principal Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).  I am modeling my matrices using Apache Commons Math3's [RealMatrix](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix.html) class.

As part of the procedure, the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix are calculated using the [EigenDecomposition](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/EigenDecomposition.html) class.  This produces two matrices:

- Columns of Matrix v are the eigenvectors
- Matrix d is all 0's except the eigenvalues on the diagonal

Example:  the original matrix is:

```
⎡0.6166 0.6154⎤
⎣0.6154 0.7166⎦
```

After decomposition, the eigenvector matrix v is

```
⎡-0.7352 -0.6778⎤
⎣ 0.6779 -0.7352⎦
```

And the eigenvalue diagonal matrix d is

```
⎡0.4908 0.0000⎤
⎣0.0000 1.2840⎦
```

The next step in the PCA procedure is to sort columns by eigenvalue (in decreasing order).   In particular since the second column eigenvalue (1.284) is higher than the first column (0.4908), I want this to be first, and sort both matrices v and d so that the columns appear in the decreasing eigenvalue order:

Resulting v':

```
⎡-0.6778 -0.7352⎤
⎣-0.7352  0.6779⎦
```

Resulting d':

```
⎡0.0000 0.4908⎤
⎣1.2840 0.0000⎦
```

I have searched SO and many places for code which does this sorting, and found either packages that do PCA in a much more complex way, or manual sorting routines for 2D Java arrays.  While I am capable of writing such a sorting routine, I will be doing this frequently on large arrays and am hoping for a prepackaged, efficient solution.  Since PCA is a standard procedure, this matrix operation should be rather common.  I am looking to see if there are any packages that already exist (e.g., Apache Commons Math) which contain methods that perform this.

An alternate solution that would permit me to reconstruct the new matrix from the old one would be to obtain an array of sort indexes from the eigenvalue columns, e.g., an array [1,0] which tells me the highest ranked eigenvalue is in column 1, and the 2nd highest ranked eigenvalue is in column 0, etc.

Can anyone point me to a package that can support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I've been able to implement the alternate solution I suggested.  I created an array of column indices ({0, 1}) and then sorted that array based on the eigenvalue corresponding to the indexed column.  Then I simply created a new RealMatrix and copied columns over from the old one in order of the sorted array:

```
for (index: sortedIndexArray) {
  vPrime.setColumnVector(i, v.getColumnVector(index)); 
  dPrime.setColumnVector(i, d.getColumnVector(index)); 
  i++;
}
```

Still wondering if there's already a method in a package somewhere that does this...